# Disk goes to recovery mode

Tags: hard-drive, centos7

We are running an application with 3 disks in a server. OS is CentOS 7. Intermittently one of the disks goes to recovery mode. CentOS file `/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/state` changes to recovery automatically and the disk is not accessible. On reboot it is normal again. Have anyone faced this?

Comment: You have a good backup ?

Comment: Yes we have a backup. But want to know the reason why a disk goes to recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

Usually going into recovery for a single disk is a sign of a disk that is about to fail and in your case the controller kicked it out of the array when the disk was stressed, but when the server booted the controller spin it and then it re-add it back into the array as now without stress the disk seem ok.

I would replace it in prevention. It's like having a car tire that always deflate when you run on it. You can put air into it to start back, but can you  thrust it for a big & safe ride on the highway ?